# Matplotlib: Picker not working with a plot which has twiny()

Tags: matplotlib, plot, picker

I have a rather simple plot with a picker implemented as:

```
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    line, = ax1.plot(x_ut, y_brightness, marker='o', picker=10)

    def pick_handler(event):
        if isinstance(event.artist, Line2D):
            ind = event.ind
            print 'deleting data point:', ind, np.take(x_ut, ind), np.take(y_brightness, ind)
            del x_ut[ind[0]]
            del y_brightness[ind[0]]
            line.set_data(x_ut, y_brightness)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', pick_handler)
```

The picker works fine (I click on a data point in the plot, it disappears and the plot is updated). But as soon as I add a secondary x-axis (and I really need it) to the plot as:

```
    ax2 = ax1.twiny()
```

the picker stops working, just nothing is happening. (The picker does not deal with the secondary x-axis, it deals only with data points plotted along the primary x-axis and is, thus, entirely detouched from the secondary one.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a known limitation of twin axes. From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html): "For those who are 'picking' artists while using twinx, pick events are only called for the artists in the top-most axes."

Comment: Well, I dont intend to use the picker on the secondary x-axis, the picker deals with data points plotted along the primary x-axis (is this one the top-most one?), while the secondary x-axis only shows some ticks and values. Hence, according to the docs, if I understand them right, my picker still should be able to work, since it is entirelly detouched from the secondary x-axis.

Comment: In that case, set the zorder of the first plot to be higher than the second one `ax1.set_zorder(ax2.get_zorder()+1)` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30506077/5851928)

Comment: @DavidG Yay! That did the trick! The picker works now. Thank you!