# MatplotLib line behind bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the function detailed below. It works perfectly well to produce the bar and line plot for the comparisons I am after but the line is behind the bars. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
The `lineInput`, `barInput`, and `xlabel` variables are a `pd.DataFrame` rows where the others are `str` or `bool`s.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def plotLineBarResults(xAxis, lineInput, barInput, lineLabel, barLabel, xlabel, ylabel1,ylabel2, yformat, title,legend = True, grid=True):
    fig, ax =plt.subplots()
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
 
    
    ax.set_xticklabels(xAxis,rotation=45, ha="right")
    line1 = ax.plot(xAxis,lineInput, label = lineLabel, color = 'red')
    line2 = ax2.bar(xAxis, barInput, label = barLabel)

    ax.set_title(title)
    if legend:
        lines = line1+[line2]
        labs = [l.get_label() for l in lines]
        ax.legend(lines, labs,frameon = False, facecolor = 'white')
   
    if grid:
        ax.xaxis.grid(True,linestyle = '--')
        ax.yaxis.grid(True)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel1)
    ax2.set_ylabel(ylabel2)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter(yformat))
   

    fig.show()
```

Comment: I have tried to use the zorder input into the plots but that does not appear to work either

Comment: Your title mentions a `boxplot` but I only see a `bar` plot. Which do you mean?

Comment: apologies - yes you are right it is a bar plot.

Comment: Set the zorder of `ax` rather than `line1` so that it's on top of `ax2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to arrange plots of secondary axis to be below plots of primary axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505616/how-to-arrange-plots-of-secondary-axis-to-be-below-plots-of-primary-axis-in-matp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot the line plot separately and then overlay it on top of the bar plot using `zorder`. Here's how you can do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter


def plotLineBarResults(xAxis, lineInput, barInput, lineLabel, barLabel, xlabel, ylabel1, ylabel2, yformat, title,
                       legend=True, grid=True):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

    ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel1, color='red')
    ax1.bar(xAxis, barInput, label=barLabel, color='blue', alpha=0.7)

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax2.plot(xAxis, lineInput, label=lineLabel, color='red', marker='o', linestyle='-', linewidth=2, markersize=6,
             zorder=2)
    ax2.set_ylabel(ylabel2, color='red')

    ax1.set_xticks(range(len(xAxis)))
    ax1.set_xticklabels(xAxis, rotation=45, ha="right")

    ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

    ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter(yformat))

    if legend:
        lines, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
        lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
        ax2.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, loc='upper left', frameon=False, facecolor='white')

    if grid:
        ax1.xaxis.grid(True, linestyle='--')
        ax1.yaxis.grid(True)

    ax1.set_title(title)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Here's and example/use case:

```
xAxis = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
lineInput = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
barInput = [5, 12, 8, 18, 10]
lineLabel = 'Line Data'
barLabel = 'Bar Data'
xlabel = 'Categories'
ylabel1 = 'Line Y-Axis'
ylabel2 = 'Bar Y-Axis'
yformat = '%.0f'
title = 'Line and Bar Plot Example'


plotLineBarResults(xAxis, lineInput, barInput, lineLabel, barLabel, xlabel, ylabel1, ylabel2, yformat, title)
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: Your bar and line axes are swapped, which is why your solution works. The twin axis goes in front. But if they want to keep the same axes order, this won't work.